# 部品間でのIMEModeの自動切替について

Tags: c#, .net

WindowsFormの部品ごとのIMEModeの自動切替についての質問です。
WindowsFormアプリにて、部品ごとにフォーカスイベントにフックをかけてIMEModeを設定しています。
しかし、ある部品から他の部品を選択した際にフォーカスイベント
で設定しているはずのIMEModeが無視され、IMEModeが設定できません。
なぜなのでしょうか。
ブレークを張り処理が通っていることは確認しています。

※どうもIME自体が保持している、部品ごとのIME設定をIMEmodeの設定値に関係なく書き戻しているように思われます。
IMEmode設定用に部品でフックしているイベントは、TextBoxではEnterとLeaveです。
DataGridViewではCellEnterとCellLeaveです。

環境：windows10(1809) C# .Net3.5 VidualStudio2008

Comment: Windowsの設定で、「アプリ ウィンドウごとに異なる入力方式を設定する」のチェックは入っていますか？入っていませんか？（設定→デバイス→入力→キーボードの詳細設定　でアクセスできる場所です）

Comment: 該当チェックですが、すでに試しています。どうやらWindows8.1から該当チェックボックスの仕様が変更されたようです。少なくともWindows10での該当チェックの意味は、アプリごとに異なる「言語」を設定できるという意味です。異なるIMEを設定できるという意味ではなくなっています。https://answers.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/forum/all/アプリウイ/dd70bd74-df83-466e-b30c-fff8b2496e6b?auth=1